# At what scale does auto incrementing in MongoDB become problematic?

Tags: mongodb

There are countless posts about auto incrementing being a bad idea at scale. I'm wondering if my project is small enough for it to be an issue.

When does auto-incrementing become a bottleneck?
1,000 writes/day
10,000? 100,000? ...

I'm looking for a general ballpark. The writes I'm doing are <= 100kB in size.

Comment: I have found problems in SQL databases (never done AI in MongoDB, of course) after about 20 million rows on standard single node hardware but since MongoDB does it's I relatively the same as SQL but client side then you can say it is about the same.

Comment: It depends on your hardware, naturally, but at 1,000, 10,000, 100,000 writes per day it should not be a problem at all.  100,000 writes per day is not much more than one per second. On server-class hardware you should be able to go 3 or more orders of magnitude beyond that.